# Pushing to GitLab repo does not trigger the Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab, gitlab-ci

gitlab plugin Version: **1.4.2**

jenkins Version: **2.7.4**

gitlab Version: GitLab Community Edition **8.11.4**

I have followed the plugin documentation and setup the webhook accordingly

(https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin).

- Added gitlab repo to the jenkins job, the connection test succeeds.
  Building the jenkins job manually also succeeds (The code is fetched
  from the repo correctly so no issues there)
- Added the webhook for jenkins. Testing the webhook also succeeds
  (returns HTTP200). But on the jenkins side. nothing happens as a
  result of the test even after it was performed after a change to the
  repo (the jenkins log and gitlab plugin log show no activity)
- When I try to test the whole setup. I make a new push to the gitlab
  repo to see if it triggers a new build on jenkins. But nothing
  happens. Can anybody help me out with this? I am not sure what is
  wrong here as both the test hook and test gitlab connection show
  success.

Thankyou in advance.

Naveed

Comment: can you give your jenkins job configuration

Comment: It is simple free style job, fetching code from the GitLab Repo and then executing some build commands on the code.

Comment: Follow the instructions described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782950/jenkins-and-gitlab-webhook-isnt-running/40215293#40215293

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jenkins you install and configure  (global and job) [Gitlab Hook Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin)

in your webhook can you make this :

URL : http://your-jenkins-server/gitlab/notify_commit or http://your-jenkins-server/gitlab/build_now.

Trigger : you check Push Events

and try again

To trigger a specific job the URL is:
http://your-jenkins-server/gitlab/build_now/job_name

job_name is the name of the job created in jenkins

Comment: Be careful with the plugin "Gitlab Hook Plugin". At this moment, the current version has security issues.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions here and everything worked quite well: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example. It is possible to give back the results of the jenkins job to GitLab pipelines.

You can also push back the results using the jenkins pipeline:

```
node {
  gitlabBuilds(builds: ['Build', 'Test', 'QA']) {
    stage('Build') {
      gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Build') {
          sh "your execution"
      }
    }
    // The rest of the stages here...
  }
}
```